# laravel regex VS php regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation, model

I have a controller and a model that must validate data before the storing process.

I try to validate a phone number by a regex(in my model,$rules).

```
        'phone'     => array(
            'required',
            'regex:/(\+41)\s(\d{2})\s(\d{3})\s(\d{2})\s(\d{2})/',
        ),
```

And when I test it(Postman), it's return : {"error":{"phone":["The phone format is invalid."]}}

Here's the phone number(Swiss) : +41 79 228 95 16

First I tried my regex on : https://regexr.com and my number seemed perfectly match with it.

So here's my question :

Does the regex's laravel is different from the PHP's regex that I test on regexr.com?

Thanks !!

Comment: Sometimes it can happen due to \ being an escaping character, you could try \\+41 and so on to all the \ to ensure they are being evaluated as you expected.

Comment: @Mikey thanks for the answer
But it doesn't change anything

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the rest, but it could also be due to the `regex:` it may be treating that as the delimiter, and since it isn't replicated on the end - it may believe the pattern hasn't been ended.

Comment: The validation works for me. What's your controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pattern should be `/(\+41)\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{3}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}$/`

Comment: Thanks it works !

But I dont understand why the regex was correct without it online but wasn't in my code...